# Surjective homomorphism from the pullback of the pushforward of a quasi-coherent sheaf to itself

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm working on problem 5.2.16 in Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*.

Let $f : X \to Y$ be an affine morphism and $\mathcal{F}$ a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$. We would like to show the canonical homomorphism $$f^*f_*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$$ is surjective.

We want to show the stalk map at $x$ is surjective for all $x \in X$: $$(f^*f_*\mathcal{F})_* \cong f_*\mathcal{F}_{f(x)} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \mathcal{F}_x.$$ I know in general $f_*\mathcal{F}_{f(x)}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}_x$, but I'm not sure how they are related. Could someone give me a hint on how to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps try and understand this in the case where both $X$ and $Y$ are affine. Then figure out how your question can be reduced to this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may assume that $Y=\operatorname {Spec}A$ is affine.
 Then $X$ will be affine too, $X=\operatorname {Spec}B$, and $f$ will correspond to a ring morphism $\phi:A\to B$.
The quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}=\tilde N$ will be associated to some $B$-module $N$ and the canonical map $f^*f_*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$ corresponds to the canonical  $B$-module morphism $$s:{_AN}\otimes_AB\to N:n\otimes b\mapsto bn$$  where $_AN$ is the $A$-module obtained from $N$ by the restriction of scalars $\phi:A\to B$.
Since $s(n\otimes 1_B)=n$, $s$ is surjective and thus the required canonical map $$\tilde s:f^*f_*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$$  is surjective too by exactness of the functor quasicoherentification™

Comment: Could you also talk a bit more about the functor quasicoherentification? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear Claud, quasicoherentification is the functor $M\to \tilde M$ from $A$-modules to $(\operatorname {Spec}A)$-Sheaves of Modules described in Hartshorne on page 110. Proposition 5.2 recapitulates all one has to know in practice about that functor.